# Excel VBA autofit event handler

Tags: excel, vba, triggers, eventhandler

I'm trying to trigger a function when the auto fit column (or row) is triggered by the user. So when a user double clicks on the line between the column headers in order to automatically change the column width.

I can change the column width with a function in VBA: `Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit`, but I would like to have the event `handler` / `trigger` for it ...

Comment: There is no event exposed for that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no event for autofit, but there is a way to make sure that it stays the same as you desire. Thus, you may use `_Change` event with a constant for the width:

```
Private Const STANDARD_WIDTH = 6

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A:A").ColumnWidth <> STANDARD_WIDTH Then
        Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = STANDARD_WIDTH
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this helps but won't fire if the user doesn't change the selection.